# Split file into 4 chunks using macOS version of split package

Tags: osx, gnu, split

In GNU/Linux in order to split file into 4 equal chunks we can do something like:

```
split temp -n 4 PREFIX_
```

But seems like the macOS' BSD version of `split` utility doesn't have `-n` option.
What would be the analog of GNU split command in macOS?

Comment: well it's actually macos high sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MacOS contains crippled BSD versions of coreutils. Head also does not support negative byte counts, while it's GNU analog allows to do something like `head -c -1`.

I ended up installing GNU version of coreutils on MacOS:

```
brew install coreutils
```

This installs all the coreutils including split and head with prefix `g`. So now I can do:

```
gsplit ${file} -n 4 PREFIX_
```

And

```
ghead -c -1 ${file}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the size of the file and divide it by 4 and use MacOS's `split -b` on the number of bytes instead. I don't have a way to test this, but loosely:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=myfile
size=$(stat -f '%z' "$myfile")
let part=size/4
[ "$part" = 0 ] && part=1
split -b "$part" "$myfile" ...
```

I don't know what happens when the size is under 4 bytes and you say `split -b 0`, so make it 1.
See the man pages [split](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/) and [stat](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html).